# Different Engine/Prop Sizes on Same Wing/Single Craft?

Tags: wing, fly-by-wire, vtol, propeller-aircraft, air-data-computer

On a four propeller/engine wing, I’m wondering if theoretically at least, you could have a larger engine near the root of the wing with smaller engine(s) further out on the span..?.. If you could have the smaller propellers further out spin faster on smaller diameters and counter-rotate them... It's a pretty high wing so we can vary the prop diameter pretty well. The airframe design already has lots of vertical stabilization opportunities.

The engines would be diesel operating, generally at high torque at the 1500-2350 rpm range (further out on the wing engines would be rotating faster with high pitch at about 2200 rpm during cruise). On such a wing with different sized and powered engines would it be feasible to balance the torque-roll effects with computers (to calculate roll, yaw and pitch (relative to the NE Downframe?) angles on the fly), accelerometer sensors (arduino), spacing of the engines, construction of wings, vertical surfaces, tip tanks in the wings and air frame and rotating speed to rotating mass per diameter to feathered mass differentiation, etc.,?

Thanks so much,
Greg

Comment: While I'm not exactly sure what type of aircraft you're building, it sounds like it is quite a bit larger than a simple model aircraft. If this is true, I would strongly suggest not using an Arduino for any safety-related purpose. Arduino boards are meant for hobbyist use; they are not reliable enough for aircraft systems.

Comment: When you say " theoretical ", the answer is generally almost always yes. I don't see a real question in here though, mostly just musing about what might be possible. What is the purpose of this thought experiment?

Answer (score 6):

The [Bird Innovator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_Innovator) was an American four-engined executive amphibious airplane modified from a Consolidated PBY Catalina by the Bird Corporation.

During the late 1960s Forrest Bird and his Bird Corporation developed a conversion for the PBY Catalina to improve performance.

The Catalina was modified by adding two 340 hp Lycoming GSO-480-B2D6 engines positioned outboard of the original Pratt & Whitney radials to increase range and performance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No need to be so complicated, as long as you *pair* your engines, one on either side.

Putting a lighter engine nearer the wing tip may have been what Hugo Junkers had in mind with [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junkers_G.38) aircraft, long before the computer age.

The V12 inboards swung 4 bladed props, the outer 6 cylinder engines had 2 bladed props.